# Angular subscribe to HTTPClient Observable, error req.url.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: angular, observable, httpclient

I am using a service to retrieve data from a url, I am using that service in another component to display the data in Frontend...

My service:

```
getHttpData(baseurl, prefix?, suffix?, startTime?, endTime?, demo_id?)  {
    return this.http.get(baseurl+ prefix + suffix+ startTime + endTime + demo_id).map(
      (res: Response) => {return this.data = res;}
    )
  }
```

My component that uses the service:

```
ngOnInit() {
baseurl: 'http://localhost:6666/some/tra/la/la98321'; 

    this.data = this.genHttp.getHttpData(this.baseurl).subscribe(result => {
      this.data = result;
      console.log('Daten:',this.data);
    });

  }
```

But I get the following error in console:

> core.js:1633 ERROR TypeError: req.url.toLowerCase is not a function
>       at HttpXsrfInterceptor.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept
>   (http.js:2027)
>       at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle
>   (http.js:1407)
>       at HttpInterceptingHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptingHandler.handle
>   (http.js:2080)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http.js:1158)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext
>   (mergeMap.js:117)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next
>   (mergeMap.js:107)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:93)
>       at Observable._subscribe (scalar.js:5)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe
>   (Observable.js:176)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
>   (Observable.js:161)

How would I have to do it to retrieve the data without an error?

Comment: please share your interceptor code

Comment: Did you find solution? I faced the same error earlier. I wasn't adding api url properly and I think this happens when request string is not correct/properly written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly try this and let me know

```
getHttpData(baseurl, prefix?, suffix?, startTime?, endTime?, demo_id?)  {
        const url= baseurl+ prefix + suffix+ startTime + endTime + demo_id+'';
        return this.http.get(url).map(
          (res: Response) => {return this.data = res;}
        )
      }
```

Comment: thanks, I looked into my backend and I get:  localhost:6666/some/tra/la/la98321undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined... so it seems the optional parameters are initialised as "undefined", so I replaced the url and set default values: "", that seemed to work...